# What are invalid characters for a file name under OS X?

Tags: macos, path, filesystems, osx-lion

I am having trouble finding this information, and trial and error is telling me that there may not be any. What are invalid characters for a file name on OS X Lion (10.7)?

Comment: Single forward slash ? Single backslash ? Single or double period ?

Comment: All the slash combo's and singles seem to work, but a single and double period do fail because they are already in use.  I hope there is more than that.... :)

Comment: You can't use an ASCII NUL. Think a while and you might spot why yourself…

Comment: @Donal ASCII NUL is not something you can easily just "type" or do problematically by mistake.

Comment: @rodney what on earth has what you can easily type by accident got to do with anything. Do you want help or not?! Sheesh!

Comment: Can you give us some context, Rodney? It would help a lot in answering this if we understood a little bit about what you're trying to do... AFAIK, there are a few potential issues: honest-to-god *forbidden* characters, characters that are impossible to enter as a path in a terminal shell, and characters that won't display properly in Finder.

Comment: Looking for the Apple doc that give's the specifics of what is legal or not thats really it. I can find MSDN Doc's on Windows, and ones for each Linux platform about this, but nothing from Apple I can find.  Its a simple question that context shouldn't really matter if you know the answer, if you do not then do not comment or try to answer its simple.

Comment: It's built on BSD, so my educated guess would be "it's the same as UNIX". Check my answer, though.

Comment: @Rodney: The key point I was making is that NUL is illegal, _precisely because_ it is the marker for the end of the filename.

Comment: @DonalFellows im writing a filename validator function in Mathematica. it will take a string as input. what would an ASCII NUL (or any ASCII 1 - 31 control characters) look like if they had been deliberately written into a string that would be used for creating a file or directory name? I ask so I know what to search for in strings. do any of these look correct for  NULL? "filename&#00;", "filename\00", "filename\0", "filenameNUL", "filenameNULL"

Comment: @DonalFellows please permit me to ask it a different way. how might i go about searching a string for codes not permitted in windows filenames? does this `win = FromCharacterCode[#] & /@ Range[0, 31]` to go with `StringReplace` look like a good start?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[HFS Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS+) allows "[Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), any character, including NUL. OS APIs may limit some characters for legacy reasons"

Comment: Techincally the HFS+ file system does allows all Unicode characters (since it represents names internally as Pascal strings with a 2-byte length), but AFAIK none of the APIs provided by OS X allow you create/open files with a slash `'/'` or NUL `'\0'` in them.

Comment: APIs as in Carbon or Cocoa? I assume Terminal is under such restrictions, but what about scripts run by other programs, such as launchd?

Answer (score 14):

[What are invalid characters for a file name under OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/326103)

[wiki HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS+):

> **Allowed characters in filenames** Unicode, any character, including NUL. OS APIs may limit some characters for legacy reasons

---

Finder doesn't currently allow entering colons in in file names, but it does allow entering backslashes. However the characters shown as slashes in Finder are shown as colons in shells, and vice versa. Finder doesn't allow any ASCII control characters either.

---

Bash seemed to allow all control characters except `\000` (NUL). I tested it by running the output from:

```
for i in {1..31} 127 0; do echo touch \\$(bc <<< "obase=8;$i"); done
```

Comment: Could you test `/` (POSIX path separator) and `:` (HFS path separator) with bash?

Comment: Confirmed by experiment that every glyph on a standard QWERTY keyboard is permitted by MacOS Finder _except_ colon. That's not quite what OP asked, but might be relevant to others.

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED**

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename), the only invalid character is the forward-slash `/`, but at the UNIX layer.

Comment: Maybe `:` is prohibited on Mac OS Classic, but certainly not on Mac OS X—`touch foo:bar` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Answer has been updated. You're welcome to remove your downvote.

Comment: @Adam: `:` is valid in the “unix layer”, but it is translated to/from `/` in the “Mac layers” (i.e. Finder, most file-related dialogs, etc.): the colon is used as the separator in “HFS paths” and the slash is used as the separator in “POSIX paths” so there is a two-way translation depending on which “layer” you are working with.

Comment: So, no forward slash (`/`) or colons (`:`) to be safe?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yes. Finder.app won’t allow you to enter a colon, and won’t work properly with filenames that contain it. The UNIX layer won’t allow you to work with files containing a slash (or rather; it translates it to a colon). And then there are other applications (such as Microsoft Word) who choke on either. For instance, if you save a document in TextEdit.app under the filename `foo/bar.docx` (which works), Microsoft Word will be unable to open it.