# Does Mac OS accept colon ( : ) in filename?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

I'm looking for illegal characters in filenames for Mac OS. I'm getting mixed answers about colon `( :)`

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/326103/what-are-invalid-characters-for-a-file-name-under-os-x) it's saying Mac OS X does accept colon.

Comment: No, it's says it's acceptable at the unix layer, which isn't quite the same thing. Finder won't let you use them. For the opposite reason, you shouldn't use forwards slash `/` either as the unix layer will swap them to `\:`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate. I think the answers in the linked question (particularly the 2nd answer) very clearly say that MacOS Finder doesn't support colons (you can use it in Finder, and it will have issues showing/using the file.)

Answer (score 1):

I quote the
[answer by user Phoenix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173621/452951)
from the post
[When did the colon character : become an allowed character in the filesystem?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173529/when-did-the-colon-character-become-an-allowed-character-in-the-filesystem)

> This is due to the difference in command line and GUI.  As pointed out
> in the above comment, colon (":") is allowed in UNIX/BSD since the
> directory delimiter is slash ("/").  In the GUI, the delimiter is
> colon and slash is allowed as a character for a file.
>
> Mac OS X interchanges those characters depending on where you view
> them.
>
> So, if a file is viewed in command-line, it shows colon.  If it is
> viewed in the GUI (e.g. Finder or TextWrangler), it shows slash.
>
> In other words: You could use TextWrangler to create a file named "/"
> and then later view that same file in command-line, where it would be
> displayed as ":".
>
> Generally, I would avoid using either of the characters, if not
> required by a specific naming convention.  In the end, it is a file
> name and does not affect the contents of that file. Using an
> underscore (oldskool) or a space character would be recommended.

The
[answer by user Dan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173631/452951)
adds :

> This change appeared at the beginning of MacOS X (i.e. MacOS X 10).
>
> Then the directory separator from HFS `:` was changed to the directory
> separator of UFS `/`. Since then the `Finder` is in charge of making
> the following mapping:
>
> ```
> / → :
> : → /
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can.**

You just need to use the terminal for it.

**Steps :**

1. go to some safe test-directory using `cd` command
   (you can skip this, not recommended though)
2. then run :

```
echo "apple is a fruit" > "banana:banana.txt"
```

This will create a file with name `banana:banana.txt`

you can verify this by running :

```
ls -lah
```

This will show all the files in the current-drictory.

**You can see the file's content using**

```
cat banana:banana.txt
```

Comment: The trouble with doing that is that the Finder will display it as `banana/banana` & more confusingly if you drag the file onto terminal rather than examine it directly wi `ls` then it will call it `banana\:banana`